# how can I loop through files in a folder and subfolders using electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have a desktop app that I am making that requires me to loop through a folder and all of it's subfolders to find files with a certain character in their name. is this possible using electron? I can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what I am currenlty using in an electron app I am building

```
const iterateDir = () => {

    const files = [],
        dirs = [];

    return function dirIt(directory) {

        try {

            let dirContent = fs.readdirSync(directory);

            dirContent.forEach( path => {

                const fullPath = join(directory,path);

                if ( fs.statSync(fullPath).isFile() )
                    files.push(fullPath);
                else
                    dirs.push(fullPath);
            });

            if ( dirs.length !== 0 )

                dirIt(dirs.pop());

            return files;

        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
            return false;
        }
    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go through folders and subfolders by using the npm package, glob.
in this demonstration, only files are sent to the console, but if you were to send the variable 'res' to the console, you would get an array with all of the folders and files in the selected folder.

as an aside, normally chrome can't view folder paths, that's why I used the function '.path'. it is created by electron to serve that purpose. in the html file, I use

```
<input id="directoryVal" type="file"
       webkitdirectory />
```

so that I may browse for a folder.

```
var getDirectories = function (src, callback) {
  glob(src + '/**/*', callback);
};
listdir.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var directoryVal = document.getElementById('directoryVal').files[0].path
    getDirectories(directoryVal, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
      } else {

        for (i=0; i< res.length; i++){
            if (fs.lstatSync(res[i]).isDirectory() == false){
                console.log(res[i]);
            }


        }
      }
    });
})
```